# What to do as an international student without a driving license that is needed for PPL Training in Germany?

Tags: flight-training, ppl, germany

I am required by the Luftamt Südbayern to provide information from the driving suitability register from the Federal Motor Transport Authority in Germany but I do not have a German driving license as I am an international student.

Anyone with any ideas as to how I should approach this?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need a driving license to request information from the German Register of Driver Fitness.

The Kraftfahrt-Bundesamt has a website in English with information on how to request your information free of charge: https://www.kba.de/EN/ZentraleRegister_en/FAER_en/Auskunft_en/faer_auskunft_inhalt_en.html?nn=642934

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I appreciate it.